# form in modal action not doing anything

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This is some code from my index.html. My issue is that the action on the form in the modal is not working (no error, just doing nothing) yet the form outside the model is working fine (commented test button). The model is opening fine and seems correctly formatted, yet the 'yes' button does nothing but closes the modal. The problem does not seem to be in the URL. Any help would be much appreciated. I am using django by the way

```
{% for patient in all_patients %}
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <!-- Name -->
    <h4>{{ patient }}</h4>

    <!-- View Details -->
    <a href="{% url 'patients:patientInfo' patient.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">View Details</a>

    <!-- Edit Details -->
    <a href="{% url 'patients:patient-update' patient.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit Details</a>

    <!-- Delete Patient -->
    <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="{{ patient.id }}" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#patient_id">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="patient_id" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

              <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm delete</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure you want to delete {{ patient }}?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <form action="{% url 'patients:patient-delete' patient.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

        <!-- test button -->
        <form action="{% url 'patients:patient-delete' patient.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% cycle '' '' '' '' '' '<div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>' %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what should it do?

Comment: It is supposed to be a confirm delete patient popup

Comment: Try removing `data-dismiss="modal"` from the `button` that doesn't work